# How to replace \" in a string with \\"?

Tags: c#

I would like to replace \" in a string with \\" using c#.
I wanna escape this character. I cant find and replace \ with \\.

Comment: Indeed duplicate of many other topics

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string actually contains `\"` (for instance, `string myString = "\\\";`) you could use

```
myString.Replace("\\\"", "\\\\\"");
```

If your string contains `"` (for instance, `string myString = "\"";`) you could use

```
myString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\","\\\\");
```

You escape \ with \, so \ indicate a single \ inside a non-verbatim string

**EDIT**

A bit confused now. You don't only want to replace \ with \ but \" with \"? Then it goes like this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("\\\"","\\\\\"");
```

Since \" is the escape char for "

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "@" verbatim to escape special characters inside a string:

```
string a = @"\";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, try replacing the quote with a slash and a quote. :)

```
string myString ="\"\"";
myString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
str = str.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

or

```
str = str.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```